# How to get count of received notification for All applications in Anroid

Tags: android, android-notifications, usage-statistics

[image]Read notification count based on package name(For All applications) with daily basis received notification count.

*Even if uninstall app and install again after few days then also show the notification count for every days.*

Answer (score 0):

Using NotificationListenerService we can easily read the notification of all application. Check complete demo code [here](https://www.androiddevelopersolutions.com/2015/05/android-read-status-bar-notification.html)

Comment: it will not work if user Uninstall the app then we can't get notification count. See this [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.burockgames.timeclocker) in this app shows the all notification count even if uninstall the app then install again after some days or after some notification received then still it's show the notification count properly.